# Получить geoJSON полигоны напрямую онлайн

Tags: javascript, geojson

Я использую карты leaflet, и мне нужно выделить определенные регионы. Я делаю выделение с помощью полигонов geoJSON. На данный момент использую такую ссылку
`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Russia&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson` т.е. с этой страницы получаю координаты (geoJSON), и вставляю на карту. Но проблема этой страницы в том, что вместе с координатами он дает мне еще и метки, а на карте мне они не нужны. И такой вопрос, **есть ли еще такие сервисы, предоставляющие напрямую страницы с geoJSON?**

вот на всякий [код с codepen](https://clck.ru/M8926)

Comment: может быть они внутри geojson?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мне тоже так кажется, но точно не знаю

Comment: поишите там «Point»

Comment: @StrangerintheQ действительно https://imgur.com/gMgz1er, это было на одной из страниц, наверняка есть и на других. Но как теперь получить этот geojson без этих point-ов?

Comment: можно их фильтрануть

Comment: @StrangerintheQ можете показать как? и желательно оставить как ответ

Comment: я хотел, но у меня что -то stacksnippets не работает, попозже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто отфильтровать GeoJson по типу геометрии:

```js
let map = new L.Map('map', {
  layers: new L.TileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'),
  center: new L.LatLng(60, 110),
  zoom: 2,
  minZoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 3
});

function doFetch(url, settings){
  fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    json.features = json.features.filter(f => f.geometry.type !== "Point")
    L.geoJSON(json, settings).addTo(map);
  });
}

function LowCoV(geoJsonData) {
  let polygonSettings = {
    fillColor: "#e00",
    color: "#f00",
    opacity: 1,
    weight: 0.5,
    fillOpacity: 0.2
  }
doFetch(geoJsonData, polygonSettings)

}
function MiddleCoV(geoJsonData) {
  let polygonSettings = {
    fillColor: "#e00",
    color: "#f00",
    opacity: 1,
    weight: 0.5,
    fillOpacity: 0.5
  }

  doFetch(geoJsonData, polygonSettings)
}
function HightCoV(geoJsonData) {
  let polygonSettings = {
    fillColor: "#e00",
    color: "#f00",
    opacity: 1,
    weight: 0.5,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
  }

  doFetch(geoJsonData, polygonSettings)
}

LowCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Russia&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson');
LowCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=USA&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson');
LowCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Canada&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson');
LowCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Spain&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson');
LowCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Russia&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson');

LowCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=France&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson');
LowCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Italy&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson');
LowCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=India&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson');
LowCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Germany&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson');
MiddleCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Japan&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson')
MiddleCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Australia&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson'); // Russia polygons
HightCoV('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=China&polygon_geojson=1&format=json'); // China polygons
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  #map {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ, но можете еще на последок дать совет по тому, как увеличить скорость определения полигонов. А то как сами видите они загружаются только через несколько секунд

Comment: @nosferatu-id я думаю это просто много данных, надо упрощать полигоны, наверное